# if input is nth term in fibonacci series, finding n

Tags: fibonacci, series

in fibonacci series let's assume nth fibonacci term is T. F(n)=T. but i want to write a a program that will take T as input and return n that means which term is it in the series( taken that T always will be a fibonacci number. )i want to find if there lies an efficient way to find it.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: well for different range i can pick a number which i can be sure of is greater than n. for higher range it can be sqrt(T). then by brute-force, i can check for all n decreasing from that number if F(n)==T. well it's just an wild idea and not realistic. that's why i need halp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to simply start generating Fibonacci numbers until F(i) == T, which has a complexity of O(T) if implemented correctly (read: not recursively). This method also allows you to make sure T is a valid Fibonacci number.

If T is *guaranteed* to be a valid Fibonacci number, you can use approximation rules:
[Formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#formula)

It looks complicated, but it's not. The point is: from a certain point on, the ratio of F(i+1)/F(i) becomes a constant value. Since we're not generating Fibonacci Numbers but are merely finding the "index", we can drop most of it and just realize the following:

```
breakpoint := f(T)
Any f(i) where i > T = f(i-1)*Ratio = f(T) * Ratio^(i-T)
```

We can get the reverse by simply taking Log(N, R), R being Ratio. By adjusting for the inaccuracy for early numbers, we don't even have to select a breakpoint (if you do: it's ~ correct for i > 17).

The Ratio is, approximately, 1.618034. Taking the log(1.618034) of 6765 (= F(20)), we get a value of 18.3277. The accuracy remains the same for any higher Fibonacci numbers, so simply rounding down and adding 2 gives us the exact Fibonacci "rank" (provided that F(1) = F(2) = 1).

Comment: The easy way would be `O(i)` instead of `O(T)`, I think.

Comment: How? i isn't an input parameter. T is a sufficient upperbound because F(T) >= T.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an input parameter. The easy version of `f(T)` runs in `O(f(T))` time, where `f(T)` can be simplified further, probably giving you `O(log T)`. You're right that that's also `O(T)`. I made the all too common mistake of reading `O(T)` as `Θ(T)`. A simple linear search is `O(n)`, `O(n^2)`, `Θ(n)`, but not `Θ(n^2)`.

Comment: But O(i) (or Θ(i)) is meaningless either way and it does have to be an input parameter. The entire point of complexity bounds is to have some notion of how inputsize affects runtime.

Comment: But `i` is a function applied to an input parameter. Functions applied to input parameters are perfectly valid and common in big O notation. Or do you also object to `O(log T)`?

Comment: I just noticed something confusing: I used T both as "the input" as "the breakpoint". I meant the first definition. T is a constant, thus meaningless in any bound notation. i is not a function; it's simply a notational concept (counter/iterator/whathaveyou). N (or T in its first definition) is the only input parameter and thus the only option for bound notations.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. I was assuming (pseudo-code) `f(T) { i = 0; while (F(i) != T) ++i; return i; }` and referring to the *final* value of `i`, which is pretty clearly exactly the same thing as `f(T)`, not any earlier values it gets.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to implement fib numbers in a non-recursive way such as

```
fib1=0;fib2=1;
for(i=startIndex;i<stopIndex;i++)
{
     if(fib1<fib2)
     {
        fib1+=fib2;
        if(fib1=T) return i;
        if(fib1>T) return -1;
     }
     else
     {
        fib2+=fib1;
        if(fib2=T) return i;
        if(fib2>t) return -1;
     }
}
```

Here startIndex would be set to 3 stopIndex would be set to 10000 or so.  To cut down in the iteration, you can also select 2 seed number that are sequential fib numbers further down the sequence.  startIndex is then set to the next index and do the computation with an appropriate adjustment to the stopIndex.  I would suggest breaking the sequence up in several section depending on machine performance and the maximum expected input to minimize the run time.